# select multiple patterns with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have file that looks like that:

```
t # 3-7, 1
v 0 104
v 1 92
v 2 95
u 0 1 2
u 0 2 2
u 1 2 2
t # 3-8, 1
v 0 94
v 1 13
v 2 19
v 3 5
u 0 1 2
u 0 2 2
u 0 3 2
t # 3-9, 1
v 0 94
v 1 13
v 2 19
v 3 7
u 0 1 2
u 0 2 2
u 0 3 2
```

t corresponds to header of each block.

I would like to extract multiple patterns from the file and output transactions that contain required patterns altogether.

I tried the following code:

```
ps | grep -e 't\|u 0 1 2' file.txt
```

and it works well to extract header and pattern 'u 0 1 2'. However, when I add one more pattern, the output list only headers start with t #. My modified code looks like that:

```
ps | grep -e 't\|u 0 1 2 && u 0 2 2' file.txt
```

I tried sed and awk solutions, but they do not work for me as well.

Thank you for your help!
Olha

Comment: Why did you use `&&` instead of `\|` like when you added the second pattern?

Comment: @anubhava The `t` lines don't have `0 1 2` on them.

Comment: Ah that's right, in that case `grep -E 'u 0 [12] 2|t'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` as the separator before the third alternative, just like the second alternative.

```
grep -E 't|u 0 1 2|u 0 2 2' file.txt
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to specify a filename and also pipe `ps` to `grep`. If you provide filename arguments, it doesn't read from the pipe (unless you use `-` as a filename).

Comment: So, this give me both options, t # 3-436, u 0 1 2, u 0 2 2 and t # 3-437, u 0 1 2. How can I keep exact match (meaning t # 3-436, u 0 1 2, u 0 2 2 only)?

Comment: You mean you only want the `t #` line if there were `u` lines matched in that block? I don't think you can do that with `grep`, you need something programmable like `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep with multiple `-e` expressions to grep for more than one thing at a time:

```
$ printf '%d\n' {0..10} | grep -e '0' -e '5'
0
5
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@kojiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403280/96588), you'll want to [use an array to collect arguments](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050):

```
mapfile -t lines < file.txt
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
    arguments+=(-e "$line")
done

grep "${arguments[@]}"
```

You'll probably need a condition within the loop to check whether the line is one you want to search for, but that's it.